# Linq EF6 Merging two lists

Tags: sql, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, knockout-3.0

My application is MVC5, MS SQL.  I am trying to develop a dynamic survey using KnockoutJs.
I need to develop an array that contains each question information as follows:

```
var jsonData = [
        {
            Name: "Are you happy?",
            Type: "Yes/No",
            Options: [
                { id: "1", name: "Yes", Qid: "1", Question: "Question", Qtype: "Yes/No" },
                { id: "2", name: "No", Qid: "1", Question: "Question", Qtype: "Yes/No" }
            ],
            Default: "" 
        }
```

The Options / name is stored in the database as a comma separated column; I used string_spilt to generate rows for each name. In the SQL view each question is repeated.

I get the options using:

```
var grid = _db1.vw_thesurvey.AsNoTracking().Where(c=> c.SurveyId == surveyid).DistinctBy(p => new { p.Qid }).Where(c=> c.SurveyId == 1)
                .Select(h =>new {
                 Options = new
                    { 
                    name = h.name, id = h.id, Qtype = h.Qtype, Qid = h.Qid}
                }).ToList();
```

This produces 9 rows for three questions (2,3,4 rows per question).
I get other question information using:

```
 var grid1 = _db1.SurveyQuestions.AsNoTracking().Where(c => c.SurveyId == surveyid).Where(c => c.SurveyId == 1)
                .Select(h => new {
                    Name = h.Title,
                    Type = h.Type,
                    Default = ""
                }).ToList();
```

This produces three rows. My challenge is how to merge the two lists to generate the required array.

Answer (score 0):

It's better to use a model class(in your case probably Options) having `Name, Id, QType, QId, Default` attributes, and select this class in your `Select` in both of your LINQ queries. This will give the list of same types then you can combine both of the lists easily.

First list will look like this:

```
var grid = _db1.vw_thesurvey.AsNoTracking().Where(c=> c.SurveyId == surveyid).DistinctBy(p => new { p.Qid }).Where(c=> c.SurveyId == 1)
            .Select(h =>new Options() { 
                Name = h.name,
                Id = h.id,
                QType = h.Qtype,
                QId = h.Qid,
                Default = ""
               }).ToList();
```

And second list Like:

```
 var grid1 = _db1.SurveyQuestions.AsNoTracking().Where(c => c.SurveyId == surveyid).Where(c => c.SurveyId == 1)
            .Select(h =>new Options() { 
                Name = h.Title,
                Id = 1, //Some default values, if you want otherwise you can omit
                QType = h.Type,
                QId = 1, //Some default values, if you want otherwise you can omit
                Default = ""
               }).ToList();
```

And then you can add the second list in the first one like:

grid.AddRange(grid1);

I hope it resolves your problem.